Unity - AudioClip GetData
I would like to have some clarity on the GetData method of AudioClip.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.GetData.html
Here is the given example of the method :
    float[] samples = new float[audioClip.samples * audioClip.channels];
    audioClip.GetData(samples, 0);

What is the correspondance of samples ? Why is the array size multiplied by channels ?
Does the float[] samples correspond exactly to the audio passed (eg the first float is the start and last float is the end of the audio ?)
If not, is there a way to have the data corresponding at the audio ?

Assuming there are 2 channels, they are arranged like this:
Channel 0 Sample 0,
Channel 1 Sample 0,
Channel 0 Sample 1,
Channel 1 Sample 1,
...

